# The logistic distribution PDF

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If I have

$$F(x)= \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$

How may I find the PDF?

Comment: Just differentiate w.r.t $x$ by using quotient rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule, differentiating gives $\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}$, which is notably an even function. It's often worth noting $F^\prime=F(1-F)$.